# Facing InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While creating new user i am getting error as below.
I am using Spring-data-jpa and have created UserRepository for that also.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**UserDesc.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DESC")
public class UserDesc implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 758374824732125303L;
    private String userId;
    private String password;    
    private String emailId;
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public UserDesc() {
    }

    public UserDesc(String userId, String password, String firstName, String updtUserid, Date timeStamp,
            String lastAction) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.updtUserid = updtUserid;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.lastAction = lastAction;
    }

    public UserDesc(String userId, String password, String emailId,  Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.password = password;
        this.emailId = emailId;     
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    public UserDesc(String userId, String emailId, String password) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 250)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID", length = 100)
    public String getEmailId() {
        return this.emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }


    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userDesc")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IVMT_USER_ROLE")
public class UserRole implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7237890967514573717L;

    @Id
    private UserRoleId id;
    private RoleDesc roleDesc;
    private UserDesc userDesc;


    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(UserRoleId id, RoleDesc roleDesc, UserDesc userDesc ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.roleDesc = roleDesc;
        this.userDesc = userDesc;

    }

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 50)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "roleName", column = @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)) })
    public UserRoleId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UserRoleId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public RoleDesc getRoleDesc() {
        return this.roleDesc;
    }

    public void setRoleDesc(RoleDesc roleDesc) {
        this.roleDesc = roleDesc;
    }

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "IVMT_USER_DESC")
    public UserDesc getUserDesc() {
        return this.userDesc;
    }

    public void setUserDesc(UserDesc userDesc) {
        this.userDesc = userDesc;
    }
}
```

**UserRoleId.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserRoleId implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3699646506024636048L;
    private String userId;
    private String roleName;

    public UserRoleId() {
    }

    public UserRoleId(String userId, String roleName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

**RoleDesc.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IVMT_ROLE_DESC")
public class RoleDesc implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3095436060121680832L;
    private String roleName;
    private String roleDesc;

    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public RoleDesc() {
    }

    public RoleDesc(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;

    }

    public RoleDesc(String roleName, String roleDesc,
            Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.roleDesc = roleDesc;

        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getRoleName() {
        return this.roleName;
    }
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    @Column(name = "ROLE_DESC")
    public String getRoleDesc() {
        return this.roleDesc;
    }
    public void setRoleDesc(String roleDesc) {
        this.roleDesc = roleDesc;
    }
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roleDesc")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

Creating new User code as below.

```
userDesc = new UserDesc(userId, emailId, password);
Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
RoleDesc roleDesc = roleRepository.findByRoleName("USER")
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
UserRoleId id = new UserRoleId(signUpRequest.getUserId(), roleDesc.getRoleName());
UserRole userRole = new UserRole(id, roleDesc, userDesc);
userRoles.add(userRole);
userDesc.setUserRoles(userRoles);
userRepository.saveAndFlush(userDesc);
```

Error Full Stack:

```
Hibernate: select TOP(?) userdesc0_.user_id as col_0_0_ from ivmt_user_desc userdesc0_ where userdesc0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select TOP(?) userdesc0_.user_id as col_0_0_ from ivmt_user_desc userdesc0_ where userdesc0_.email_id=?
Hibernate: select roledesc0_.role_name as role_nam1_9_, roledesc0_.last_action as last_act2_9_, roledesc0_.role_desc as role_des3_9_, roledesc0_.time_stamp as time_sta4_9_, roledesc0_.updt_userid as updt_use5_9_ from ivmt_role_desc roledesc0_ where roledesc0_.role_name=?
Hibernate: select userdesc0_.user_id as user_id1_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_date1 as cf_user_2_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_date2 as cf_user_3_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_date3 as cf_user_4_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_date4 as cf_user_5_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_date5 as cf_user_6_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_flag1 as cf_user_7_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_flag2 as cf_user_8_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_flag3 as cf_user_9_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_flag4 as cf_user10_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_flag5 as cf_user11_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_num1 as cf_user12_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_num2 as cf_user13_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_num3 as cf_user14_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_num4 as cf_user15_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_num5 as cf_user16_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch1 as cf_user17_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch2 as cf_user18_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch3 as cf_user19_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch4 as cf_user20_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch40001 as cf_user21_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch40002 as cf_user22_11_0_, userdesc0_.cf_user_vch5 as cf_user23_11_0_, userdesc0_.contact_no as contact24_11_0_, userdesc0_.email_id as email_i25_11_0_, userdesc0_.first_name as first_n26_11_0_, userdesc0_.last_action as last_ac27_11_0_, userdesc0_.last_name as last_na28_11_0_, userdesc0_.middle_name as middle_29_11_0_, userdesc0_.password as passwor30_11_0_, userdesc0_.time_stamp as time_st31_11_0_, userdesc0_.updt_userid as updt_us32_11_0_ from ivmt_user_desc userdesc0_ where userdesc0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select userrole0_.role_name as role_nam1_12_0_, userrole0_.user_id as user_id2_12_0_, userrole0_.last_action as last_act3_12_0_, userrole0_.role_desc as role_des4_12_0_, userrole0_.time_stamp as time_sta5_12_0_, userrole0_.updt_userid as updt_use6_12_0_, userrole0_.user_desc as user_des7_12_0_ from ivmt_user_role userrole0_ where userrole0_.role_name=? and userrole0_.user_id=?
2020-05-13 15:26:16.857  WARN 8840 --- [onPool-worker-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2020-05-13 15:26:16.857 ERROR 8840 --- [onPool-worker-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'role_desc'.
2020-05-13 15:26:16.859  INFO 8840 --- [onPool-worker-3] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4379) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1168) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1033) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:750) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:477) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:762) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:569) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.kap.IM.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kap.IM.controllers.UserController.lambda$4(UserController.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'role_desc'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    ... 71 common frames omitted

2020-05-13 15:26:16.865 ERROR 8840 --- [nio-7070-exec-2] c.k.I.a.exception.IvmtExceptionHandler   : null

com.kap.IM.api.exception.IvmtException: Unable to create new user
    at com.kap.IM.api.IvmtBaseRestController.buildErrorResponse(IvmtBaseRestController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kap.IM.controllers.UserController.lambda$5(UserController.java:87) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1595) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1592) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.kap.IM.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kap.IM.controllers.UserController.lambda$4(UserController.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390)

2020-05-13 15:26:16.868  WARN 8840 --- [nio-7070-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [com.kap.IM.api.exception.IvmtException: Unable to create new user]
```

Let me know where I am making mistake in setting proper joins between tables.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace with the exception.

Comment: @JensSchauder added full stack error in main request.

Comment: `SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'role_desc'` It looks like your schema isn't properly setup.

Comment: There is some column mapping missing between UserDesc, UserRole, RoleDesc entity and it is causing issue. database is setup properly have proper joins between above entities